# Get distinct count of product_id column based on distinct group using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I want to get total count of product_id column based on  category column by applying group by clause on category column, I wrote mysql query for that but it didn't work as per my requirement.

mysql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category  FROM `product`  group by product_id,category
```

table:

```
category      product_id
a              1        
a              1
a              2
b              3   
b              3
b              5
```

Expected output:

```
 category    count(product_id)
 a            2
 b            2
```

Comment: Are you sure about the "Expected Result" there

Comment: yes, it should group category as well as product_id

Comment: If I wanted to count something, I would expect to include the word 'count' somewhere in the query

Comment: yes, you are right I thought distinct and group by will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `count(distinct ...)`:

```
select category, count(distinct product_id) cnt_distinct_products 
from product 
group by category
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=905fcb2ec58a7948efbdf6958f79e114)**:

Sample data:

```
category | product_id
:------- | ---------:
a        |          1
a        |          1
a        |          2
b        |          3
b        |          3
b        |          5
```

Results:

```
category | cnt_distinct_products
:------- | --------------------:
a        |                     2
b        |                     2
```

Comment: can you please check once my expected out put and table

Comment: Before responding so quickly, take the time to test the proposed request. I'm sure you didn't put the correct "group by"

Comment: @GMB thanks for your answer it is working fine,  actually i missed group by  as you suggested in your answer

Comment: @A.Baudouin: this seems to me like a straight-forward aggregate query. I added a DB Fiddle to my answer for your reference.